# npm start errors - React.js

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to run a server so I can start coding my website. However, I run "npm start" I have been greeted [with errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Os32t.png). The steps to fixing this error are laid out, however, for step three I do not see babel-loader within my package.json. In addition, I am not sure if the npm ERR!(s) I get on the bottom are caused because of the issue on top or another issue in itself.

[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsC0G.png)

["runs" npm ls babel-loader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGQz3.png)

Comment: Did you try step 7? Also. look in your lockfile (package-lock.json/yarn.lock) for `babel-loader` and that will tell you what dependencies are pulling it in. In the future, you should paste the actual text instead of screenshots.

Comment: @Nick just updated the post to let you see what's in it! Will keep that in mind for next time. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have globally installed `babel-loader@8.0.2`. See #6, it points to the exact case you have.

Remove it from your home directory and that should fix it.

Comment: Hey, where should this be installed then? Thanks for the feedback :)

Comment: Maybe not at all. How did it get there?